# ASP.NET UserControl - null reference?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a problem with my user control. Inside it, I have a checkbox control. I want to create that user control on the fly and insert it into asp:table control.

```
        MyControl pp = new MyControl();

        pp.pageNameCb.Text = "lorem";

        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        tc.Controls.Add(pp);
        table.Rows[0].Cells.Add(tc);
```

But, the `pageNameCb` is null, even if I create its instance by hand, nothing displays in my table. Why ?

Here's my code:

```
   <asp:View ID="new_role_view" runat="server">
        <asp:Table ID="table1" runat="server">
           <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server">
              <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell1" runat="server">

              </asp:TableCell>
           </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </asp:View>
```

Then, if I change that view is active, I create my control:

```
        MyControl pp = new MyControl();
        table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls.Add(pp);
```

the MyControl's Page_Init:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pageNameCb == null)
            pageNameCb = new CheckBox();
        pageNameCb.Text = "works";
    }
```

and still, nothing shows

Comment: in which method of the page are you executing this code? try also to set an ID for pp after you create it.

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Check generated HTML and see if the checkbox really added in the table or not

Answer (score 0):

When you create you user control are you instantiating the checkbox at the same time? It will be null unless the checkbox is created at some point. If it were a custom control you would create in Control.CreateChildControls - as it's a user control in the constructor maybe or a custom method - Init() or somesuch.

Also I would create the user control on Page_Init then add to control tree there otherwise it won't participate in the ViewState of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that should work fine if your user control's is created well according to `ASP.net Page Cycle`.

Initialize checkbox on User Control's Page_Init() event if you are adding that checkbox dynamically.  and provide some `ID` to your control.

```
 private Table CreateHtmlTable()
        {
            Table table = new Table();
            table.Rows.Add(new TableRow());          

            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
            MyControl pp = new MyControl();
            pp.ID = "SomeID";
            pp.pageNameCb.Text = "lorem";
            tc.Controls.Add(pp);
            table.Rows[0].Cells.Add(tc);

            return table;
        }
```

This is code which working fine for me...

> ```
> ASPxLabel lbl = new ASPxLabel();
> lbl.ID = "lblTopicName";
> lbl.Text = "TopicName";
> table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls.Add(lbl);
> ```